# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'function' and 'int' probability calculator

Tags: python

I'm trying to put my probability calculator inside a nice GUI but I ran into a problem with my probability calculations.

I've made 3 scripts:

1. Tkinter script, my user interface and also the place where I get
   my numbers from.
2. My runable script, this script has been put in place to prevent
   circular imports. This is also the script that I run to use my
   "program"
3. My probability calculator, it collects data from the Tkinter GUI,
   does a calculation and sends the output again to the Tkinter script
   to show the result in the GUI

> Scripts
>
> ```
> > Tkinter GUI, called testtennisGUI.py
> ```

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk
import csv
import tennisGameProbability


def invullen():
    resultaat.set(str(" Game = "+("{0:.2%}".format(tennisGameProbability.game_prob()))))


def result_first_service_percentage():
    return calculate()

frame = Tk()


def calculate(*args):
    try:
        value_player1c = float(v1player1.get())/100
        value_player1d = float(v2player1.get())/100
        value_player1e = float(v3player1.get())/100
        result_player_1.set(str("{0:.3}".format((((value_player1c * value_player1d)-(value_player1c * value_player1e)) + value_player1e)*100)))
        return ((value_player1c * value_player1d)-(value_player1c * value_player1e)) + value_player1e
    except ValueError:
        pass

resultaat = StringVar()
resultaat2 = StringVar()
b1player1 = StringVar()
v1player1 = StringVar()
v2player1 = StringVar()
v3player1 = StringVar()
result_player_1 = StringVar()

c_player1 = Label(frame, text="1st Service Percentage:").grid(row=3, column=1, sticky='w')
cc_player1 = Entry(frame, text="value", textvariable=v1player1, justify='center', width=10).grid(row=3, column=2)
d_player1 = Label(frame, text="Points Won on 1st Serve: ").grid(row=4, column=1, sticky='w')
dd_player1 = Entry(frame, text="value", textvariable=v2player1, justify='center', width=10).grid(row=4, column=2)
e_player1 = Label(frame, text="Points Won on 2nd serve:").grid(row=5, column=1, sticky='w')
ee_player1 = Entry(frame, text="value", textvariable=v3player1, justify='center', width=10).grid(row=5, column=2)
projected_player1 = Label(frame, text="Projected Hold").grid(row=6, column=1, sticky='w')
my_result_player_1 = Entry(frame, textvariable=result_player_1, justify='center', width=10).grid(row=6, column=2)
my_resultaat = Label(frame, textvariable=resultaat, justify='center').grid(row=8, column=1, columnspan=2, pady=10)
my_resultaat_2 = Label(frame, textvariable=resultaat2, justify='center').grid(row=9, column=1, columnspan=2, pady=10)


f = open('testtennis.csv')
csv_f = csv.reader(f)
players_names = []
for row in csv_f:
    players_names.append(row[0])


def new_selection(event):
    return player1()

box_value = StringVar()
box = ttk.Combobox(frame, textvariable=box_value, justify='center')
box.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", new_selection)
box['values'] = players_names
box.current()
box.grid(column=2, row=1, pady=20, padx=15)


def player1():
    with open("testtennis.csv") as fh:
        for row in fh:
            if (box_value.get()) in row:
                player_name = row[0:row.find(',')]
                row = row.replace(player_name+',', '')
                first_service = row[0:row.find(",")]
                row = row.replace(first_service+',', '')
                points_first_serve = row[0:row.find(",")]
                row = row.replace(points_first_serve + ',', '')
                points_second_serve = row[0:row.find(",")]
                row.replace(points_second_serve + ',', '')
                v1player1.set(first_service)
                v2player1.set(points_first_serve)
                v3player1.set(points_second_serve)


run = ttk.Button(frame, text='Run', command=invullen)
run.grid(column=1, row=7, columnspan=2, ipadx=15, pady=25)
mainloop()
```

> The script that I run, called run_file.py

```
import testtennisGUI


def projected_hold_player1():
    return testtennisGUI.result_first_service_percentage()
```

The calculation script, called tennisGameProbability.py

```
from run_file import projected_hold_player1


def fact(x):
    if x in [0, 1]:
        return 1
    r = 1
    for a in range(1, (x + 1)):
        r = r * a
    return r


def ch(a, b):
    return fact(a) / (fact(b) * fact(a - b))
    pass


def game_outcome(s, a, b):
    return ch((a + b), a) * (s ** a) * ((1 - s) ** b) * s


def game_prob(s=projected_hold_player1, v=0, w=0):
    if v >= 4 and (v - w) >= 2:
        return 1
    elif w >= 4 and (w - v) >= 2:
        return 0
    else:
        pass
    while True:
        if (v + w) > 6:
            v -= 1
            w -= 1
        else:
            break
    if w == 0:
        w0 = game_outcome(s, 3 - v, 0)
    else:
        w0 = 0
    if w <= 1:
        w15 = game_outcome(s, 3 - v, 1 - w)
    else:
        w15 = 0
    if w <= 2:
        w30 = game_outcome(s, 3 - v, 2 - w)
    else:
        w30 = 0
    if v == 4:
        wad, lad = s, 0
        d = 1 - s
    elif w == 4:
        wad, lad = 0, 1 - s
        d = s
    else:
        wad, lad = 0, 0
        a = 3 - v
        b = 3 - w
        d = ch((a + b), a) * (s ** a) * ((1 - s) ** b)
    if v <= 2:
        l30 = game_outcome((1 - s), 3 - w, 2 - v)
    else:
        l30 = 0
    if v <= 1:
        l15 = game_outcome((1 - s), 3 - w, 1 - v)
    else:
        l15 = 0
    if v == 0:
        l0 = game_outcome((1 - s), 3 - w, 0)
    else:
        l0 = 0
    denom = s ** 2 + (1 - s) ** 2
    wd = (d * (s ** 2)) / denom
    ld = (d * ((1 - s) ** 2)) / denom
    win = w0 + w15 + w30 + wd + wad
    lose = l0 + l15 + l30 + ld + lad
    return win
    return game_prob()
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
File "C:\Users\Magali\PycharmProjects\Wouter\tennisGameProbability.py", line 19, in game_outcome
    return ch((a + b), a) * (s ** a) * ((1 - s) ** b) * s
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'function' and 'int'
```

When I manully put in values in the tennisGameProbability script than it works.
So I think the issue is with the way my variable data gets moved between the scripts. I've tried everything I know but without any luck.

Who can tell me where my mistake is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are clearly assigning the default value of `s` as a function:

```
from run_file import projected_hold_player1

...

def game_prob(s=projected_hold_player1, v=0, w=0)
#             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

So calling `s**a` raises that error, as the operator does not specify any behavior for function types.

You should instead assign `s` to the return value of the function `projected_hold_player1`, provided the value is a number, which I think it is.

```
def game_prob(s=None, v=0, w=0):
    if s is None:
         s = projected_hold_player1()
```

Or you could call the function while assigning the default value.

```
def game_prob(s=projected_hold_player1(), v=0, w=0)
#                                     ^^
```

Comment: when I try your fist solution I get the error: if s in None:
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

Comment: When I try your second option than I get the error:     return testtennisGUI.result_first_service_percentage()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'result_first_service_percentage'

Comment: I fixed a typo with the first part `in` `->` `is`

Comment: And what if I want to make v and w based on user input from the Tkinter script?

Comment: You could assign them a default value of `None` in the function definition and ask the user for input in the function if their values are `None` at runtime